# JPA cascade remove

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa

I'm facing a problem while deleting a record that is referenced by another table.

This is a code example (simplest scenario):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="user_id_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="user_id_seq", sequenceName="user_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<UserLog> userLogSet;

    // Other attributes
    // Getters/setters
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_log")
public class UserLog
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="user_log_id_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="user_log_id_seq", sequenceName="user_log_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    // Other attributes
    // Getters/setters
}
```

Whenever I try to delete a record from the "user" table, I get the following error from postgreSQL:

> ERROR: update or delete on table "user" violates foreign key
>   constraint "fk228a019fd2495d20" on table "user_log"
> Detail: Key
>   (id)=(5) is still referenced from table "user_log".

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

**Update:** I tried coding a small example, it can be found [here](https://github.com/MintTwist/Cascade-Test). After launching the application with Tomcat the database schema is automatically created (check the connection details in /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties). When you visit http://localhost:8080 some data is inserted in the database. If I try to delete any `teacher` who is referenced in the `student` table (using phpPgAdmin), I get an error similar to the one above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping seems to be wrong.

User can have many UserLogs I guess.

Also `@OneToMany` should be on a collection e.g. `java.util.Set`.
The cascade you have put is in UserLog which will take place if you act on instance of UserLog and not User.

As far as I understand change mapping as follows.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="user_id_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="user_id_seq", sequenceName="user_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="user")
    private Set<UserLog> userLogs;

    // Other attributes
    // Getters/setters
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "user_log")
public class UserLog
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="user_log_id_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="user_log_id_seq", sequenceName="user_log_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    // Other attributes
    // Getters/setters
}
```

I guess you want to delete User and all its UserLog simply deleting User and leaving UserLogs doesn't make sense.

Hope this helps.

**Update:**

> Cascades as annotated in entity classes are managed by ORM, not if you
>   externally try to delete them from external tools like phpPgAdmin.

Comment: Thank you, @gbagga--see my comment in madth3 question, I just got confused posting the example here. Now the point is that I don't need the `Set` in the `User` class, is it mandatory? Is there anyway to avoid having it?

Comment: @satoshi its not mandatory to use Set, its basically used so that duplicates objects don't end up in collection with objects. In case you are interested have look @ hibernate [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html)

Comment: Thank you, @gbagga. Unfortunately I face the same problem even with your solution. Should JPA/Hibernate create indices in PostgreSQL? Or all the cascade actions are managed by the ORM? Thank you.

Comment: @satoshi try adding orphanRemoval = true to `@OneToMany` annotation

Comment: Done already, doesn't work anyway. I'm going to build this exact simple example in order to see if it works. It could be that in my project in doesn't work because I use AspectJ or something else...

Comment: Ok, I tried with a small example and it doesn't work anyway. You can find the example here: https://github.com/MintTwist/Cascade-Test (updated original question)

Comment: as you updated your question what exactly do you want to do, delete teacher and all students referenced by that teacher should also get deleted? if you delete teacher and if referenced by student it is not deleted is correct due to foreign key constraint.

Comment: Yes, I want students related to the teacher to be deleted as well. This is the whole point of `CascadeType.REMOVE` (which is included in `CascadeType.ALL`), right? How can I achieve it otherwise..? Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9330/discussion-between-gbagga-and-satoshi)

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is wrong, the `OneToMany` should be in `User` applied to a collection of `UserLog`'s. See [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html).

Comment: Sorry, you're right. In the code I'm working on I'm using `ManyToOne`, I just got confused posting an example here. (edited the original question)